# Как передать указатель через функцию

Tags: c++, указатели, glfw

У меня появилась проблема с передачей указателя через функцию, то есть мне нужно получить указатель из класса через функцию "геттер" которую я написал в этом классе. Но когда я вызываю этот "геттер" он возвращает мне пустой указатель.

Код класса где объявлен "геттер":

```
class Window {
private:
    GLFWwindow* m_window;
private:
    int FPS;

    unsigned int projUniformLocation;
    unsigned int transUniformLocation;
    unsigned int viewUniformLocation;
    unsigned int colorUniformLocation;

    float m_LastFrameTime = 0.0f;
public:
    glm::mat4 projection;
    glm::mat4 view;

    GLFWwindow* getMainGLFWWindow() { return m_window; };

    int WindowDraw(int width, int height);
    void WindowUpdate();
    void WindowShutDown();
};
```

функция "геттер" - getMainGLFWWindow().

Указатель который я передаю - m_window.

.cpp файл:

```
int Window::WindowDraw(int width, int height)
{
    glfwInit();

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);  

    m_window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, "Hyko", NULL, NULL);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(m_window);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(m_window, windowResizeCallback);
    //glfwSetKeyCallback(m_window, Hyko::key_callback);
    glfwSetMouseButtonCallback(m_window, 
    Hyko::mouse_button_callback);

    if (!m_window) {
        std::cout << "Window not initialized" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    GuiWindow.createImGuiWindow(m_window);

    updates.EventStart();

    return 0;
}
```

Вызов этой функции:

```
Window m_windowC;

bool Hyko::isKeyPressed(const Hyko::keyCode keyCode)
{
    auto* window = static_cast<GLFWwindow*>(m_windowC.getMainGLFWWindow());
    auto state = glfwGetKey(window, static_cast<int32_t>(keyCode)); 

    return state == GLFW_PRESS;
}
```

При запуске программы в отладчике Visual Studio он мне пишет вот это:
"Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x00007FF730BD53B0 в OpenGL.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0x00000000000000D8".

Как мне это исправить?
И ещё, если не сложно скажите что мне нужно подучить в C++.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: ну так может `m_window` у вас не инициализируется и потом использутеся ?

Comment: недостаточно кода чтобы помочь вам - вы вобще окно или нет ?
где вызов `m_window = glfwCreateWindow(...)` ?

Comment: Всё, .cpp файл добавил. В .cpp файле инициализация окна

Comment: Самый последний код - это .cpp файл, а самый первый - это .h файл

Comment: вам известно для чего нужен конструктор класса? почему окно создается не в нём ?

Comment: и где вызов `Window::WindowDraw()` ?

Comment: Вызов WindowDraw() находится в main.cpp файле, также как и WindowUpdate() и WindowShutDown(). Добавить main.cpp файл?

Comment: Это мой первый проект с использованием ООП, поэтому тут я не использовал многое из него. А вообще сейчас я изучаю всё на ходу (именно то что мне нужно в данный момент), поэтому где-то есть новые штуки, а где-то нету

Comment: https://github.com/artemko22/Hyko_Engine.git - это мой репозиторий, однако это старая версия и там ещё нету "геттера" и функций которых я тут показал

Comment: Получится ли передавать *GLFWwindow* через функцию если переменная будет статичная?

Answer (score 0):

я решил свою проблему.
Вот как теперь выглядит код:

1. window.h файл:

   ```
    class Window {
    private:
        static GLFWwindow* m_window;
    private:
        int FPS;

        unsigned int projUniformLocation;
        unsigned int transUniformLocation;
        unsigned int viewUniformLocation;
        unsigned int colorUniformLocation;

        float m_LastFrameTime = 0.0f;
    public:
        glm::mat4 projection;
        glm::mat4 view;

        Window* Get();

        GLFWwindow* getMainGLFWWindow() { return m_window; };

        int WindowDraw(int width, int height);
        void WindowUpdate();
        void WindowShutDown();
    };
   ```
2. window.cpp файл:

   ```
    GLFWwindow* Window::m_window;
    int Window::WindowDraw(int width, int height)
    {
        glfwInit();

        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);  

        m_window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, "Hyko", NULL, NULL);
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(m_window);
        glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(m_window, windowResizeCallback);

        if (!m_window) {
            std::cout << "Window not initialized" << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }

        if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
        {
            std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }

        GuiWindow.createImGuiWindow(m_window);

        updates.EventStart();

        return 0;
    }
    ...
   ```
3. InputEvents.cpp (файл где происходит вызов "геттера"):

   ```
    bool Hyko::isKeyPressed(const Hyko::keyCode keyCode)
    {
        auto* window = static_cast<GLFWwindow*>(m_windowC.getMainGLFWWindow());
        auto state = glfwGetKey(window, static_cast<int32_t>(keyCode));

        return state == GLFW_PRESS;
    }
    дальше там тоже самое, но для обработки отжатия клавиш и нажатия|отжатия кнопок мыши
   ```

То есть вот что я сделал:

1. В window.h файле сделал переменную GLFWwindow* m_window статичной.
2. В window.cpp фале глобально добавил строчку GLFWwindow* Window::m_window;.

Я не уверен что это самое лучшее решение и мне кажется что это вовсе костыль, однако пока я решил проблему только таким способом.